# Rails Folder Structure comparison from earlier versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, directory-structure

Can anyone tell me a reference where I can find the difference between the folder structures and its specifics of Rails versions till 3.2.9?

Comment: did you try running "rake routes"?

Comment: What kind of application are you trying to run here?  Rails?  How did you start your webserver?  Please be more specific.

Comment: As per your comments, I have given you a detailed description on the scenario. Now, Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Just doing rails new  is not enough. You will need to do `bundle exec rails g scaffold <desired_app_functionality; e.g. BlogPost> name:string post:text` (as an example) to generate the proper routes; that is likely why you get "No Route Matches [Get]"... that or you deleted ./public/index.html without setting a root route in routes.rb. Here is [a guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root) to using the root in routes.rb